# Extended Definition of Measurability

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X_1, \mathcal{A}_1)$ and $(X_2, \mathcal{A}_2)$ be measurable spaces. Given a map $f\colon X_1\longrightarrow X_2$ we say that $f$ is measurable if $f^{-1}(V)$ is a measurable set in $X_1$ for every open set $V$ in $X_2$.

In Rudin's "Real and Complex Analysis, 3rd ed." the above definition is enlarged: We say that $f$ defined on a set $E\in \mathcal{A_1}$ is measurable on $X_1$ if $\mu(E^c)=0$ and if $f^{-1}(V)\cap E$ is measurable for every open set $V$.

While I understand, that the secon definition is a real extension of the first, I don't understand what he writes next.

"If we define $f(x)=0$ for $x\in E^c$, we obtain a measurable funciton on $X$, in the old sense" (Old sense = first definition). He then adds "If our measure happens to be complete, we can define $f$ on $E^c$ in a perfectly arbitrary manner, and we still get a measurable function"

I cannot see why defining $f(x)=0, \ x\in E^c$ leads to the first defintion.

Comment: There is no such thing as an open set in a measurable space, in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, presumably you mean for $X_2$ to be $\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$) and for $\mathcal{A}_2$ to be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. 
 Otherwise it does not make sense to talk about open sets or to define $f(x)=0$.

Now, if you extend $f$ by defining $f(x)=0$ for $x\in E^c$, it becomes defined on all of $X_1$.  Moreover, for any open set $V$, $f^{-1}(V)=f^{-1}(V)\cap E$ if $0\not\in V$ and $f^{-1}(V)=(f^{-1}(V)\cap E)\cup E^c$ if $0\in V$.  Either way, $f^{-1}(V)$ is measurable.  Thus this extended version of $f$ satisfies the first definition of measurability.

Comment: $(f^{-1}(V) \cap E) \cup E^c$ is just $f^{-1}(V) \cup E^c$. Why have you written it the way you have?

Comment: The point is that you know that $f^{-1}(V)\cap E$ is measurable, so you can deduce that $f^{-1}(V)$ is measurable.